# How to add a view (described in a java class) at a particular location in the layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-canvas, surfaceview

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CanvasActivity"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#f9dfcb">  
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#000000" 
    >


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CanvasActivity extends Activity {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());



    LinearLayout LinearLayout1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    LinearLayout1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
            {

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


/*********EDITED*******/

    LinearLayout LinearLayout2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);
    int width=LinearLayout2.getWidth();
    int height=LinearLayout2.getHeight();
    LinearLayout2.addView(new Canvasview(this), width, height)  ;

    LinearLayout2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

            Canvasview cv= new Canvasview(v.getContext());
            cv.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
        }
    });
}


//discerning swipes
    class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {

        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                        float velocityX, float velocityY) 
        {
             if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                     Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            //From Right to Left
             Toast.makeText(CanvasActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                  return true;           


        } 
             else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                    Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            //From Bottom to Top
            Toast.makeText(CanvasActivity.this, "Top Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return true;
        }

            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
        {

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

My Canvasview looks like this

```
public class Canvasview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private int width, height;
private Paint textPaint = new Paint();
private Paint touchPaint = new Paint();
private int colors[] = new int[10];

public Canvasview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // make sure we get touch events
    init();
}

private void init() 
{
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    colors[0] = Color.RED;


    touchPaint = new Paint();
    touchPaint.setColor(colors[0]);

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    Canvas c = getHolder().lockCanvas();

    if (c != null) 
    {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
        {
            // clear everything

        }
        else 
        {
            int xval = (int)event.getX();
            int yval = (int)event.getY();
            drawCircle(xval,yval,touchPaint,c);
        }

        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }



    return true;

}


public void clear(Canvas c){
    c = getHolder().lockCanvas();
    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

}


private void drawCircle(int x, int y, Paint paint, Canvas c) 
{
    c.drawCircle(x, y, 2, paint);

}



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){

    Canvas c = getHolder().lockCanvas();




    if (c != null) 
    {
        // clear screen
        c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

I need the canvas only in linearlayout2, but the canvas occupies the entire screen. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

EDIT:
Well I did few changes and I get the Canvasview in linearlayout2, the ontouchevents of Canvasview detects the touch events but in Canvasview public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) method does not initialize a canvas and therefore it is always null. To draw I need the canvas not to be null. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try giving the main `LiniarLayout` a `android:weightSum="4"`. But I would suggest you to find out another way to do that... weight parameter is not commanded, because the layout is calculated twice.

Comment: I would use an Andoid PopupWindow, if it is something that you wish to float on top of the main activity screen, else go backward in time, use the Andoid 2 -3 APIs and simply use an AbsoluteLayout instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".CanvasActivity"
android:baselineAligned="false">


 <View
    android:id="@+id/view0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#f9dfcb"

/>
<com.multitel.testwidget.Canvasview
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">                  
</com.multitel.testwidget.Canvasview>


</LinearLayout>
```

and changed the constructor in Canvasview to

```
public Canvasview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // make sure we get touch events
    init();
    holder.getSurface();
}
```

And i could draw on the canvas!!

Answer (score 0):

set hardcode value of layout_width for first linear layout and try again

Comment: Well I changed some part of my code LinearLayout LinearLayout2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);
  int width=LinearLayout2.getWidth();
  int height=LinearLayout2.getHeight();
  LinearLayout2.addView(new Canvasview(this), width, height) ;

Comment: But now the canvas does not detect onTouchEvent

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you want to get height and width of a view, that hasn't been drawn yet in onCreate():

```
int width=LinearLayout2.getWidth();
int height=LinearLayout2.getHeight();
```

A possible solution for that is to set static values or use a ViewTreeObserver (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+measured+width+height+android).

The other problem you might have is that linear layout doesn't call onTouch() method. You may try using a scrolling view(scrollview for example) instead of linear layout.

Comment: I just edited some part of the code, added on touch method. Th problem is surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)  needs to initialize the canvas and it is not getting into that part of the code. So even though I can detect on touch events my canvas is null and therefore i cannot draw on it

Comment: I will try what you suggested